# 'OK' button is not enabled when i try to import AzureRM Module in Azure Run books

Tags: powershell, azure

My Requirement is to run few power shell scripts in Azure Run books, I have created Azure Automation Account & Run book. Before running my power shell script i need to import AzureRM module.
Inside Automation Accounts, i clicked on Modules and In Browse Gallery and Searched for AzureRM and Selected AzureRM from the list and Clicked on Import.

i see below message

"Importing a module may take several minutes."

This module has dependencies that are not present in this account. All dependencies must be present before this module can be imported.
Dependencies:
Full List of Dependencies are listed here

And OK button underneath, OK button is not enabled even after waiting for long time.

Am i missing something ?
Note : All above listed Dependencies are already Imported manually.

Comment: Azure does not seem to thing that the dependent modules are already imported. Perhaps there is a version discrepancy between what it expects and what you imported?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot about that button to your question?

Comment: How can i share a screenshot here ? i am not finding anywhere to upload or copy screen shot. Can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a discrepancy in the dependency modules and one thing that I can suggest is to update the Azure dependency modules before adding in the AzureRM module.

However, if this does not work, you can add the AzureRM module manually by downloading the module and creating a .zip of the same. Then, you can add the module manually to Azure Automation.

Hope this helps.